# JMeter - WebDriver Sampler - waitForPopUp

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to work out a comparable command to use in jmeter webdriver sampler (JavaScript) how to do a waitForPopUp command. There must be a way. I have something that works for waiting for an element, but I can't work it out for a popup.

### Update

I am using this code for waiting for an element:

```
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)
WaitForLogo = function() {
var logo = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//img[@src='/images/power/ndpowered.gif']"))     
}
wait.until(new com.google.common.base.Function(WaitForLogo))
```

And this works, but I can't work out how reuse this to wait for a popup, that has no name, in Java I have used:

```
    selenium.waitForPopUp("_blank", "30000");
    selenium.selectWindow("_blank");
```

And that works, but I can't work out an comparable JavaScript that will work in Jmeter for performance, as I can't get Java working in Jmeter.

Comment: What kind of pop-up it is and what code you use for `waiting for an element`?

Comment: have updated my post with some more info for you, thanks for answering..

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working using:

```
    var sui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui)
```

and:

```
    wait.until(sui.ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

In WebDriver Sampler you have the following methods:

- `WDS.browser.switchTo.frame('frame name or handle')` - for switching to a frame
- `WDS.browser.switchTo.window('window name or handle')` - for switching to a window
- `WDS.browser.switchTo.alert()` - for switching to a modal dialog
- `WDS.browser.getWindowHandles()` - for getting all open browser window handles

See [JavaDoc on WebDriver.switchTo method](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo--) and [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for more details.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am looking for a method to wait for the window before switching to it, at the moment it is trying to switch too quickly and the window hasn't opened yet..

Comment: [ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#numberOfWindowsToBe-int-), Carl.